# Guardar inputfile en carpeta de servidor desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Quiero guardar mi imagen en una carpeta dentro de mi servidor, tengo el codigo en c# pero quisiera hacerlo en javascript o jquery, o como podría pasar ese método por web services?.

```
private void GuardarArchivo(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        string ruta = Server.MapPath("~/temp");

        if (!Directory.Exists(ruta))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);
        }

        string archivo = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", ruta, file.FileName);

        if (File.Exists(archivo))
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "NombreImagen()", true);
        }
        else
        {
            file.SaveAs(archivo);
        }
    }
```

Aquí defino mi método, hay alguna forma de realizar todo eso proceso con javascrit o jquery?

```
private void carga()
    {
        try
        {
            if (fileUpload.HasFile)
            {
                // Se verifica que la extensión sea de un formato válido
                string ext = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
                ext = ext.Substring(ext.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower();
                string[] formatos =
                  new string[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png" };
                if (Array.IndexOf(formatos, ext) < 0)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "FormatoImagen()", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    GuardarArchivo(fileUpload.PostedFile);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Esto lo estoy aplicando dentro de un modal y si me funciona, solo quisiera realizarlo desde js.

Comment: Javascript si no hablamos de nodejs, se ejecuta desde el lado del cliente. por lo que no tiene acceso a tu servidor. si tu backend es C# no te queda mas remedio que hacerlo en c#, siempre tendrás que implementarlo en el lenguaje de tu Backend.

Answer (score 0):

Desde JS sin ayuda de código de servidor no se puede. JS estándar no tiene acceso al file system de la pc.
Deberías usar Ajax y enviar el formulario que selecciona el archivo a un API. Es la manera correcta de hacerlo. 
Decinos si estas usando Webforms o ASP.NET MVC, para poder guiarte mejor en hacerlo.

Comment: Lo estoy realizando en WebForm, también tenía la idea de poder realizarlo desde Ajax, pero no he encontrado la manera.

Comment: Entonces lo estas intentando hacer desde C# en el postback de una acción/evento del front?

Comment: Si estas usando webforms y queres utilizar Ajax lo mejor es que crees un HTTPModule o HTTPhandler para procesar el request.